# generating pdf with queue sometimes shows old design, sometimes new design

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, vps

I am generating pdf with snappy plugin on laravel. I am using a laravel forge with custom VPS - Cloudfare .

While generating the pdf with laravel queue on a server, while  generating it, it shows sometimes old design that i wrote for that pdf, and sometimes it shows new design. By new and old I mean that, two days ago, I had written a blade template which gets used to generate pdf, then I changed that blade template to add some styles to it. If I generate pdf 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th, 9th time, it shows updated design of pdf. If I generate pdf 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th, it shows old design of pdf.

What could be the case ? why does this happen?

Comment: Are you using supervisor for the process management?

Comment: yeah. queue is a daemon.

Comment: I had a similar problem... It wasn't a PDF generation but simple job execution... I saw that without restarting the deamon, sometimes the jobs weren't executed with the updated code. I think it's the job serialization that is somehow still "cached"

Comment: I ran php artisan queue:restart, but still this doesn't make it work . what should I do?

Comment: Restart the entire deamon... If you're using laravel forge, open a terminal, connect via SSH and run `sudo systemctl supervisor restart`